# How do I find a controller for non-minimum phase systems?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Assume that we have a transer function $G(s) = \frac{B}{A}$ which has stable poles, but unstable zeros. We use the controller $Q(s) = \frac{A}{B} = G^{-1}(s)$ and we want that the loop transfer function $L(s) = QG = 1$ due to the feedback transfer function:

$$G_f(s) = \frac{QG}{1 + QG} = \frac{1}{2}$$

But the problem here is that $G^{-1}(s)$ is unstable!

**Question:**

How can I form the $Q(s)$ controller so $L(s) = c$, where $c$ is a constant for all $G(s)$ and $Q(s)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got an answer to my own question.

We have our transfer function $$G(s) = \frac{B(s)}{A(s)}$$

The best way to find the controller $Q(s)$ is to take the inverse of $G(s)$, but in this case, the zeros of $G(s)$ is positive. That means $G^{-1}(s)$ will be unstable.

The goal of this answer is to find the approximation $G^*(s)$ of $G^{-1}(s)$.

A good choice is to have this:

$$ |G(j\omega)G^*(j\omega)| = |G^+(j\omega)G^+(-j\omega)| =1 \forall \omega$$

Where $G^+(s)$ is the positive zero polynomial and $G^-(s)$ is the rest of the zero polynomial.

Example:

$$G(s) = \frac{(s+2)(s-3)}{s^2 + 1}$$

Then $B^+(s) = (s-3)$ and $B^-(s) = (s+2)$

Then we can write $G^*(s)$ as:

$$G^*(s) = \frac{A(s)}{B^+(-s)B^-(s)}$$

But we still have a problem if $deg(A) > deg(B)$, which is very common!

I will then introduce you to this correction transfer function:

$$G^*(s, m, \tau) =  \frac{A(s)}{B^+(-s)B^-(s)A_m(s, \tau)}$$

Where 
$$A_m(s, \tau) = (1+\tau s)(1+ \alpha \tau s)...(1+\alpha ^{m-1}\tau s)$$

Where $\alpha = 0.5-1$ is a tuning factor and $\tau$ is the time constant, not from $G(s)$. It's a tuning factor as well.

The choice of $\alpha = 1$ gives a multiple pole in $s = -\frac{1}{\tau}$ for degree $m >= deg(A) - deg(B)$.

Now to an example!

Let's say that we have a transfer function of a LTI system:

$$G(s) = \frac{b_0s - b_1}{as^2 + a_0s + a_1} = \frac{3s - 2}{s^2 + 3s + 1}$$

Where $B^+(s) = 3s-2$ and $B^-(s) = 1$

The inverse $G^{-1}$ looks like this:

[image]

And the $G(s)$ looks like this:

[image]

My working frequency is very low, because I want to deal with self tuning controllers, that means I will set say that

$$|G(j\omega)G^*(j\omega)| = 1 , [0 <= \omega <= 10]$$

That's my goal!

Now we need to focus on cutting frequency. We want to cut at $10$ rad/s , that means there is going to be a some dB difference between $|G^{-1}(j10)|$ and $|G^*(j10)|$.

Too choose $m$ and $\alpha$ and $\tau$ we say that:

$m = 2$, because $deg(A) - deg(B) = 1$ and $deg(A) > deg(B)$. The zeros need to be at least many as the poles, or else, our transfer function won't be proper!

That means we need to have an extra pole in $s = -\frac{1}{\tau}$ so $deg(A) = deg(B)$. The solution is $\alpha = 1$

Now we need to select $\tau$. Then we using the bandwidth formula:

$$\omega _b \tau = \sqrt{2^{1/m} - 1}$$

We know $\omega _b = 10$ rad/s and $m = 2$. Then we can find out that

$$\tau = \frac{\sqrt{2^{1/m} - 1}}{\omega _b} = \frac{\sqrt{2^{1/2} - 1}}{10}
 = 0.0643594$$

Now we can choos $A_m(s,\tau)$ as

$$A_2(s, \tau) = (1+ \alpha^{1-1}\tau s)(1+\alpha ^{2-1} \tau s) = (1+\tau s)^2$$

beacuse $m = 2$ and $\alpha = 1$. Remember: $1^0 = 1^1$.

Anyway

$$A_2(s, 0.0643594) = (1+0.0643594s)^2$$

And now $G^*(s)$ is:

$$G^*(s) = \frac{A(s)}{B^+(-s)B^-(s)(A_m(s,\tau)}= \frac{s^2 + 3s + 1}{(-3s - 2)1(1+0.0643594s)^2}$$

Simulating $G^*(s)$ will show us the blue line:

[image]

Now it's time for bode plotting

$$|G(j\omega)G^*(j\omega)|$$

[image]

Very good!

[image]

If you don't want to compute to much, you can set:

- $\alpha = 1$
- $m = 2$
- $\tau$ = 0.00000001 or a very low number

if you dealing with a second order non-minimum phase system.

The result will be:

[image]

So let's go controll engineers and control theorists, create invertible controllers like never before!

Comment: Maybe you should look into the areas of lambda-tuning/internal model control/Youla-Kucera parameterizations (in increasing order of complexity/generality) which essentially does this. If that is where you've taken the answer, you should perhaps add a suitable reference/link, so no-one reinvents the wheel.

Comment: I have never heard about that. The issue I try to solve is self tuning controllers for a non-minimum phase system.

Comment: I wonder if those formulas works for discrete systems?

Comment: I would assume the theory is well developed also for the discrete-time case. These are classical problems from the 60s and 70s.

Comment: Yes. Even if the problems is from 60's and 70's, that means that they exist today too? Most of the PID-controllers I have been installed has autotuning. I have not meet an MPC yet, but I probably will in the future.

Comment: Of course the theory still exist, and Youla-Kucera is a central results in linear systems theory. The sloppy result in terms of creating a controller in lambda tuning is "mirror unstable zeros, and low-pass filter until proper", i.e. what you do above

Comment: @JohanLöfberg you mean that the work Karl Johan Åström did, didn't solve problems so much? His book "Adaptive Control" was ment for industrial audience? The litterature I was reading was from Bengt Lennartsson at Chalmers.

Comment: In my point of view, there is no idea to have the most advanced controller for the simpliest problem. I'm not so into computing control laws from simulations, then apply them to the reality. I think selftuning controllers is the future.

Comment: I have no idea why you are talking about Åström or adaptive control. The question is about stabilizing parameterizations of LTI controllers.

Comment: Yes. But I will use that for adaptive control. I having some issues with non-minimum phase systems. Need to have that intvertible system stable. Page 119 in "Adaptive Control" if you wonder what specific issue I talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The only option would be $c=0$, but for any other value your system will be unstable. To see this you can use the Nyquist stability criterion. Namely since $L(s)$ is constant it can't make any encirclements around the minus one point, therefore the same number of unstable poles in $L(s)$ will also be present in the closed loop system.

Comment: So is there any method to design $Q(s) $?

Comment: I posted an answer now.